# Files marked system and hidden - attrib cmd not able to change them

Tags: command-line, hidden-file, system-file

Recorder had files that are marked hidden and system. They were copied to a folder on the desktop.

Changing the view, shows them. Running attrib with the appropriate switches doesn't help. (See images.)
[image: Files displaying based on view]
[image: Files hiiden by view]
[image: Attrib commands that were inputted]
Thoughts?

Edit:See below for what worked.

Comment: Have you tried attirb in a admin command prompt?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Reclaiming ownership (even though the same user was already the owner) worked, and the attrib cmd now was able to unhide the files.